# How to include or hit a php file from custom module in Drupal 8

Tags: hooks, cron

I am working on a custom Drupal 8 module. I have a seperate php script as a .php file. I want to include that file in my Drupal 8 module, in simple words I want to hit that .php file by running my module.

What is the best way to do this?

Here is my module code:

```
    function mymodule_cron(){
     //include('myphpscript.php');
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Drupal 8 is built on OOP and use PS4 autoloading with classes. In drupal 8 you create a custom service and call that. The autoloader will handle the loading of it, you don't need to include it yourself.

Comment: What's in your script?

Comment: @jaypan: Can you provide code example?

Comment: @leymannx: Script can hold any functionality like a loop which runs 10 times and echo message.

Comment: You can see an example of creating a custom service here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/structure-of-a-service-file

Comment: Consider implementing a mini custom form with a button to start a batch process. https://opensenselabs.com/blogs/tech/how-use-batch-api-drupal-8

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I cannot understand why people mark my question negative?

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. I upvoted it. I think a good answer would help explain a history lesson about drupal 7 and how files were included there. Heck, that's still available in drupal 8 - `module_load_include`. But implementing your own cron manager / plugin system is probably a bit too broad.

Comment: thanks for the comments. Please upvote it so that other will get benefits from this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard PHP `include`, `require`, and `require_once` need a known path. Often times this is not known when making Drupal contributed modules.

In Drupal 7, the standard way to include a file inside a module was using the `module_load_include` function. This is still available, but may not be suitable for test-driven development.

In Drupal 8, as @Jaypan references in a comment above, [Structure of a a service file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/structure-of-a-service-file), we can create services and use methods on a class to do things. This has the benefit of injecting dependencies to do things.

```
function mymodule_cron() {
  // This still works, but shouldn't be used for classes in the autoloader. Generally the ".inc" file extension was used instead of ".php", but it would work.
  module_load_include('php', 'mymodule', 'myphpscript');

  // Implementing your own service if you want to use \Drupal.
  \Drupal::service('mymodule.myservice')->callMethodToDoThingOnCron();
}
```